# How can I get the count of Azure function execution programmatically in c#?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

I have timer trigger azure function which runs on every minute. Is it possible to get the count of how many time the function executed in my Azure function c# code at every time function execute?

PS: I need this count to generate a sequential counter.Also with HTTP trigger function too!
Is it possible with Application Insights -> metrics with function count filter. In a way we get this count in our code ?

Comment: Hi Shailendra, since your function runs every minute, why not get the current time in c# code and calculate the time it executed ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen , if the function stops for few minutes then the calculation with time can get wrong i think ! Also i need this with HTTPS function too.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could implement it like the below picture, the variable will be shared. However if you restart your function, it will reload the variable time.

[image]

In case of the function restart, suppose you could set it with a storage queue to implement it, every time add 1 to the queue number and replace the queue.

```
public static async void Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("time");
            CloudQueueMessage message = queue.GetMessage();
            log.LogInformation(message.AsString);
            int num = int.Parse(message.AsString);
            num++;
            queue.DeleteMessage(message);
            queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(num.ToString()));

        }
```

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the execution times and there is no API to do that, you need to manually maintain the count in a datastore and fetch it using custom logic.

Comment: whoa !  Is it possible with Application Insights -> metrics with function count filter. In a way we get this count in our code ?

Comment: what i mentioned here as a datastore could be AI, you could access it based on the filters via https://dev.applicationinsights.io/